# Can't import module: Error in file resource.robot': Importing test library failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helper'

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

I'm new in Python and Robot Framework. For test project for learning i'm creating:

general_scenario.robot:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    Suite description
Resource          ../resource.robot
*** Variables ***
...


*** Test Cases ***
[Config] Extend Config Model
[Tags]                model
Extend Config Model
```

then, create keyword lib:

```
...
class ModelLibrary(ModelAbstract):
...
@keyword('Extend Config Model')
    def extend_config_model(self):
        moGen = ModelGeneral.__init__(self, 45.5, 2.04)
        moAdd = ModelAdditional(True, 0.34)
        moRoute = ModelRoute("path")
        mo = Model("ship002", moGen, moAdd, moRoute)
        print(mo.name, mo.general, mo.additional, mo.route)
        pass
```

where i want to use helper(data-model class) helper.Model.py, which import in this keyword lib, like this:

```
from helper.Model import ModelGeneral, ModelAdditional
```

also have resource.robot file:

```
Library     libs/ModelLibrary.py
Library     libs/EmulationLibrary.py
Library     helper/Model.py
```

so `>pybot general_scenarios.robot`:

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\..\resource.robot': Importing test library 'C:\..\libs\ModelLibrary.py' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helper'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\..\libs\ModelLibrary.py", line 5, in <module>
    from helper.Model import ModelGeneral, ModelAdditional

and:
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\..\resource.robot': Test Library 'Model' expected 4 arguments, got 0.
```

fix args not fixed Importing test library failed. Can't understand wats going wrong with import normal py module.

Comment: Answers *never* belong in questions. Once you figure out an answer, feel free to answer the question yourself by *posting an answer*. Yes, it's perfectly fine to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a helper module the following command will install the module In your cmd

```
pip install helper
```

Whenever you are missing a module name you will have install it through pip or third parties

Answer (score 0):

add lib to PYTHONPATH or to python home site packages

details [here](http://automated-testing.info/t/ne-importiruet-biblioteki-robotframework-python/12858)